# setting max number of entries per userid in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Say I have the following table

```
//table user_update
update_id   |   userid   |   update_message   |   timestamp
```

Is there a way to set a maximum number of entries per userid? I want to make it so after a user types say 5 updates, any more updates entered after that deletes the oldest update. I know how to do this through PHP, just curious if there's any way to do this through MySQL only.

Comment: Create a table with 10 rows and update the oldest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing this database-side would be to use a `TRIGGER` on the table.  Maybe something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_for_too_many_rows
AFTER INSERT ON User_Update
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   DO SOME LOGIC TO CHECK THE COUNT AND DELETE IF MORE THAN 5...
END;
```

Here is some additional information:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Good luck.

Comment: Hmm, seems like it's quicker just to do it with PHP. Thanks for the info, still going to check it out anyway.

Comment: I most likely would agree, depending on your needs.  Can data ever be added to the table manually or in other processes (non-PHP)?  If so, Triggers are your best approach to ensure accuracy of data (no more than 5 rows per user).  If not, then yes, PHP would work just the same.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

That is actually possible. but it is questionable if you really want to make that effort.

Read a little about 'triggers'. You can use a trigger to start an action when certain conditions are met. This way you can trigger a `delete` action on every `insert` action on that table. Then all that is left is a condition that up to five entries are kept.